# TextFiled is Blocking UITableView scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have tableview in UIViewController & I have added text filed in prototype cell. I can't be able to scroll the table view when I am dragging the text filed area in the table view. When I am hiding the text field or making user interaction disable of the text filed on that time I am able to scroll the tableview.
Any resolution will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: ok can you please include your code in question ?

Comment: The textfiled is added in nib file (in story board).   code for cell for row:              LLRM_InspectCaseViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LLRM_InspectCaseViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        
       
        
    }

Comment: LLRM_InspectCaseViewCell is my UITableViewCell class

Comment: are you using textField or textView ?

Comment: I am using textfiled here.

Comment: is there any other controls in cell except textField ? likw button, label etc?

Answer (score 0):

If the text field has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`, and it fills the `entire cell`, you can not get the cell to listen to touch. In order to get the cell to respond to touches, you need to set the `userInteractionEnabled` of the text field to `NO`.

And if you want to make the text field editable, when the cell is selected, add the following code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// get the reference to the text field
[textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

or

you have not make `textField` so large that it covers whole `cell`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: you're welcome :) If you feel that it is helping then accept answer as right green tick so other people with similar issue can use it. :)